# Save file to external storage android API 30 using React native FS

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I would like to save files to my external storage in my android and Ios devices where users have direct access to file. Currently what I am doing is saving files to `DocumentDirectoryPath` But the user doesn't have the access to the file path `/data/user/0/com.test/files/test.pdf`.I do have a solution for API levels up to 29, What I need is API 30. Is there any possible solution for the issue?

The error I encountered when I try to save it to this path `/storage/emulated/0/`shows the error `ENOENT: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`. I am using `RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath` as the path.

I have already added the necessary permission for reading,writing files.

Comment: Wel save your files to external storage.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Well you said `I would like to save files to my external storage`. Then do it.

Comment: The follow-up asked for how to do it.

Comment: Follow up? Well you ask for a solution and the solution is exactly what you want: save files to external storage. So do. You can use the same code for writing files to internal or external storage so i do not understand your problem. The only difference is a path.

Comment: But when I try to save it to this path `/storage/emulated/0/` it shows error `ENOENT: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`. I am using `RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath` as path.

Comment: Well why didn't you tell that in your post to begin with? You are supposed to tell what you did and which errors and problems you encountered. Nothing of that all here.

Comment: Sorry, my bad will add it in the question. Not well experienced in writing stack questions.

Comment: I have the same problem, needing to write to a path that is accessible when the device is connected to a PC. I was writing to  RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath +'/DCIM/myPath' previously, but that now fails after updating react-native 0.63.4 to 0.66.4 and associated changes
Note that RNFS.mkdir(above path) succeeds, I can see the created directory, but RNFS.writeFile(file_in_above_path, 'Lorem ipsum', 'utf8') fails with EPERM.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the [new storage permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) in Android 11 / SDK 30, which have not yet been addressed by react-native-fs.

If you watch [one of the issues raised to keep track](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/998), hopefully a solution will come along soon. There seem to be several workarounds (e.g. add extra permissions to manage external storage) linked from that issue report, but it appears they either

- have limited lifetime and/or
- are complex and/or
- preclude the resulting app being uploaded to the Play Store

So they may not be useful for everyone.

I've found I can access the Downloads folder using `RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath` on Android 11 / SDK 30 on my target platform for now so I can continue development. I hope that it is properly handled before release is due.

Answer (score 1):

RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).